# Dynamics crm: modify fields of another entity in a form

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

Is there a way to insert in a form something like a Quick View Form, but with the possibility to modify the fields of the related entity in the form? [This link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/294966/editing-the-quick-view-of-a-child-entity/847921) does not give a real solution, so I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't out of box to perform what you expect.

But there is fully supported [PCF control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/overview) to perform [quick View (Edit) of Record](https://stuffandtacos.azurewebsites.net/2020/04/15/pcf-quick-edit-form/).

This shall solve your requierement.